# Visit visa for Canada from Bangladesh

Tags: visas, canada, bangladeshi-citizens

What is the fastest way of obtaining a tourist visa for Canada as a Bangladeshi resident? I am a 41-year-old single woman. My religion is Hindu.

Comment: There is no fast track service: start with [Apply for a visitor visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html); your age, status, and religion should not be relevant, only why you want to visit.

Comment: @giorgio that could be an answer

Answer (score 2):

The Government of Canada does not offer an expedited visa process, but does have easily accessed online tools.

> [**Apply for a visitor visa**](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html)
>
> **Make sure you need a visa to visit Canada**
>
> Before you apply, [find out which entry document you need](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?_ga=2.105183495.523595586.1529332973-1420682779.1528551134) to visit Canada. This could be a visa or an Electronic Travel Authorization. The entry document you need depends on:
>
> - the type of travel document you plan to travel with
> - the country that issued your travel document
>     your nationality
> - your method of travel to Canada for this trip
>
> **What is a temporary resident visa / visitor visa?**
>   A temporary resident / visitor visa is an official document stamped in your passport. It shows that you meet the requirements needed to travel to Canada.
>   Most travelers require a visitor visa to travel to Canada. You may also need a visa if you are transiting through a Canadian airport on your way to your final destination.
>
> **Basic travel requirements**
>
> You must meet some basic requirements to travel to Canada. You must:
>
> - have a valid travel document, like a passport
> - be in good health
> - have no criminal or immigration-related convictions
> - convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country
> - convince an immigration officer that you will leave Canada at the end of your visit
> - have enough money for your stay.
>
> The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
>
> You may also need a [medical exam](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/medical-police/medical-exams.html) and [letter of invitation](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html) from someone who lives in Canada.
>
> **We plan to expand our fingerprint and photo requirements**
>
> **Starting July 31, 2018**, you may need to give your fingerprints and photo (biometrics) when you apply for a visitor visa if you are from **Europe, the Middle East or Africa**.
>
> Find out [if these changes may apply to you](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/campaigns/biometrics/facts.html).